# Adding the values of second column based on date and time of first column

Tags: r, addition

I have a data frame with 2 variables. the first column "X" represents date and time with format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, the values in the second column "Y" are the electricity meter reading which are taken each after 5 minutes. Now I want to add the values of each half an hour. For instance

```
X                Y  
13/12/2014 12:00 1   
13/12/2014 12:05 2  
13/12/2014 12:10 1  
13/12/2014 12:15 2  
13/12/2014 12:20 2  
13/12/2014 12:25 1
```

At the end i want to present a result as:

```
13/12/2014 12:00 9  
13/12/2014 12:30 12
```

and so on...

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Heroka, I worked something like this: with(elec, sum(elec[2:7, "electric.meter"])), and some other code but they were not giving me the exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach which actually takes `X` in count (as per [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097282/adding-the-values-of-second-column-based-on-date-and-time-of-first-column/32099607#comment52092169_32097857)).

First, we will make sure `X` is of proper `POSIXct` format so we could manipulate it correctly (I'm using the `data.table` package here for convenience)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, X := as.POSIXct(X, format = "%d/%m/%Y %R")]
```

Then, we will aggregate per cumulative minutes instances of `00` or `30` within `X` while summing `Y` and extracting the first value of `X` per each group. I've made a more complicated data set in order illustrate more complicated scenarios (see below)

```
df[order(X), .(X = X[1L], Y = sum(Y)), by = cumsum(format(X, "%M") %in% c("00", "30"))]
#    cumsum                   X Y
# 1:      0 2014-12-13 12:10:00 6
# 2:      1 2014-12-13 12:30:00 6
# 3:      2 2014-12-13 13:00:00 3
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "X Y  
'13/12/2014 12:10' 1  
'13/12/2014 12:15' 2  
'13/12/2014 12:20' 2  
'13/12/2014 12:25' 1
'13/12/2014 12:30' 1
'13/12/2014 12:35' 1
'13/12/2014 12:40' 1
'13/12/2014 12:45' 1
'13/12/2014 12:50' 1
'13/12/2014 12:55' 1
'13/12/2014 13:00' 1
'13/12/2014 13:05' 1
'13/12/2014 13:10' 1", header = TRUE)
```

---

**Some explanations**

- The `by` expression:

  - `format(X, "%M")` gets the minutes out of `X` (see `?strptime`)
  - Next step is check if they match `00` or `30` (using `%in%`)
  - `cumsum` separates these matched values into separate groups which we aggregate by by putting this expression into the `by` statement (see `?data.table`)
- The `j`th epression

  - `(X = X[1L], Y = sum(Y))` is simply getting the first value of `X` per each group and the sum of `Y` per each group.
- The `i`th expression

  - I've added `order(X)` in order to make sure the data set is properly ordered by date (one of the main reasons I've converted `X` to proper `POSIXct` format)

For a better understanding on how `data.table` works, see some tutorials [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: You have done a wonderful job here. I applied it to my datasets and they gave me the required results. Can you please do one favor; I want to understand how does your code work? A little explanation with your code will be much much appreciated. specially this one:df[order(X), .(X = X[1L], Y = sum(Y)), by = cumsum(format(X, "%M") %in% c("00", "30"))]. Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, added explanations, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, You helped me and motivated me to learn new things. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
t1 <- tapply(df$Y, as.numeric(as.POSIXct(df$X, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) %/% 1800, sum)
data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(names(t1))*1800 + 1800, origin = '1970-01-01'), t1)
```

`t1` groups the values using integer division by 1800 (30 minutes)

Comment: Thank you for your help. My data starts from d/M/Y 11:40 but this code shows the output from 11:30 to on wards 12:00, 12:30... I could not guess why it has added the values up till 11:30 when there is no data available for that. in principle this should show the results from 12:00 to on wards. what is your opinion?

Comment: @Shamaila 11:30 summed the values between 11:30-11:55, I edited the code to give the desired output.

Comment: @germcd Hello, one question please. in your code the part `*1800+1800` what does it do?

Comment: @Shamaila it's used to create the timestamp. The names of `t1`are the timestamps integer divided by 1800s. 
To get the timestamps I multiplied the names of `t1` by `1800` and added `30 minutes (1800 s)`

Answer (score 2):

Considering your data frame as `df`. You can try -

```
unname(tapply(df$Y, (seq_along(df$Y)-1) %/% 6, sum))
```

Comment: I guess this only work if their first data point is either a round hour or an half an hour.

Comment: No, this will work for every starting point. As @Shamaila already mentioned that the reading is taken every 5 minutes which means 30 minutes has 6 , 5 minute intervals hence, `%/% 6` in the code.

Comment: Yes, but the half hours wouldn't be relative to an hour. If the starting point will be at  `13/12/2014 12:10` then the first half hour will end at `13/12/2014 12:40` and so on, instead of at `13/12/2014 12:30`. Though I'm not really sure if this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am sorry, I am not quite getting what you mean to say. If you look at the code you'll realize that it has nothing to do with `X` column. So irrespective of when you start it is going to sum the first 6 elements of `Y` column.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. It ignores the `X` column, which might be important for the OP. I've already gave an example in my previous comment. If that not enough, so it doesn't matter. Will see if this is good enough for the OP.

Comment: @Ronak your code is working perfect for the data sets which starts from exactly hh:00 to on wards but just wondering for my data files which starts from 12:15 or 01:10? as David said. how to write code for that. Also, I want to merge the 6 consecutive values in X column to show 13/12/2014 12:00, 13/12/2014 12:30, 13/12/2014 1:00 and so on? Do you have any idea how to work on that? thank u both.