# Aggregate 5 minute data to hourly sums with NA's

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

My problem is as follows: I've got a time series with 5-Minute precipitation data like:

```
            Datum mm
1 2004-04-08 00:05:00 NA
2 2004-04-08 00:10:00 NA
3 2004-04-08 00:15:00 NA
4 2004-04-08 00:20:00 NA
5 2004-04-08 00:25:00 NA
6 2004-04-08 00:30:00 NA
```

With this structure:

```
'data.frame':   1098144 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Datum: POSIXlt, format: "2004-04-08 00:05:00" "2004-04-08 00:10:00"   "2004-04-08 00:15:00" "2004-04-08 00:20:00" ...
$ mm   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

As you can see, the time series begins with a lot of `NA's`, but there is measured precipitation further down, although riddled with single, less common `NA's` due to malfunction of the measuring station.

What I'm trying to achieve, is summing up the measured precipitation to hourly sums, not considering `NA's`.

This is what I tried so far:

```
sums <- aggregate(precip["mm"], 
               list(cut(precip$Datum, "1 hour")), sum)
```

Even though the timestamps are correctly aggregated to hours, all sums are `0` or `NA`. The sums are not even calculated if there is no `NA` at all.

additionally to be taken into account:

Hourly precipitation sums in meteorology always describe the cumulative sum *until* a certain hour: The amount of precipitation at 0:00 o'clock describes the sum from 23:00 the previous day *until* 0:00. So I always need to sum up the previous hour.

**Reproducible Example**

```
set.seed(1120)
s <- as.POSIXlt("2004-03-08 23:00:00")
r <- seq(s, s+1e4, "30 min")
precip <- data.frame(Datum=r, mm=sample(c(1:5,NA), 6, T))

            Datum mm
2004-03-08 23:00:00  4
2004-03-08 23:30:00  1
2004-03-09 00:00:00  2
2004-03-09 00:30:00  4
2004-03-09 01:00:00  1
2004-03-09 01:30:00  4
```

With the above example, the result I am looking for is:

```
            Datum mm
2004-03-09 00:00:00 5
2004-03-09 01:00:00 6
2004-03-09 02:00:00 5
```

Comment: For the future, please consider reading up on [ask] and how to create a [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you without the need for a lot of clarification-comments if you provide clear expected output.

Comment: In the example data frame, what should the output be? Please answer with *actual code* not a written description of the output.

Comment: Did we really go back and forth this long and you had the solution the whole time? My original solution produces that output.

Comment: No, sry it doesn't. In my desired result the sum of `2004-03-09 00:00:00` (`= 5`) is the addition of `4+1` of 23:00 and 23:30. It is shifted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding the values of second column based on date and time of first column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097282/adding-the-values-of-second-column-based-on-date-and-time-of-first-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
aggregate(precip['mm'], list(cut(precip$Datum, "1 hour")), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#               Group.1 mm
# 1 2004-04-08 00:00:00 26
# 2 2004-04-08 01:00:00 35
# 3 2004-04-08 02:00:00 25
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
set.seed(1120)
s <- as.POSIXlt("2004-04-08 00:05:00")
r <- seq(s, s+1e4, "5 min")
precip <- data.frame(Datum=r, mm=sample(c(1:5,NA), 34, T))
```

**addendum**

To your second question: If you would like measurements on the hour to be calculated with the lesser hour add `right=TRUE`:

```
aggregate(precip['mm'], list(cut(precip$Datum, "1 hour", right=TRUE)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Further Explanation**

We will create another more detailed explanation to show how the solution works:

```
p <- c("2004-04-07 23:48:20", "2004-04-08 00:00:00", "2004-04-08 00:03:20")
ptime <- as.POSIXlt(p)
#[1] "2004-04-07 23:48:20 EDT" "2004-04-08 00:00:00 EDT" "2004-04-08 00:03:20 EDT"
```

We have three dates to separate into groups. If we use `cut` without any extra arguments, the second entry `"2004-04-08 00:00:00 EDT"` will be grouped with the third entry for hour `"00:00"`:

```
cut(ptime, "1 hour")
#[1] 2004-04-07 23:00:00 2004-04-08 00:00:00 2004-04-08 00:00:00
```

But if we add the argument `right=FALSE` we can group it with the `"23:00"` hour:

```
cut(ptime, "1 hour", right=TRUE)
#[1] 2004-04-07 23:00:00 2004-04-07 23:00:00 2004-04-08 00:00:00
```

We can specify the behavior of edge cases.

**edit**

With your new data the original solution produces the desired output:

```
aggregate(precip['mm'], list(cut(precip$Datum, "1 hour")), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
              Group.1 mm
1 2004-03-08 23:00:00  5
2 2004-03-09 00:00:00  6
3 2004-03-09 01:00:00  5
```

Comment: your Solution is succesfully deleting all the `NA's` but still, no sum is being calculated, every hour has a sum of `0`.

Comment: Have you tried the reproducible example? If your data differs, please indicate where.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Thanks to your example I realized, that the preciptiation column was not loaded correctly as a numeric variable, as the decimal seperator was a `,`... germans...!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but now - to do it correctly - the sum of e.g. 18:00 is the sum from 18:00 - 19:00, which actually should be the sum from 17:00 - 18:00.

Comment: Second question addressed in answer

Comment: `right = TRUE` unfortunately does not give the correct result. The sum of 0:00 sums up from 23:00 to 0:00 and so on, cumulating the sum _until_ 0:00.

Comment: Your expected output is unclear. Just as we did with the first question, I would like to stress the importance of creating examples. If you create a small example with your desired output, it is so much easier to help. I think you know at this point that I am honestly trying to assist you. Please help me by adding a specific example to your original post.

Comment: I edited my post though I don't know how to be more specific. Thank you very much for your great effort.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you are confused by what I mean by "an example". I will add a sample data frame to your question. Please respond with the correct answer that should result.

Comment: @candles_and_oranges Hi, I also adapt this function to aggregate 5-Minute data to daily sums, but now the problem is I found R adapt the local timezone directly, which means the daily sum values are at 1:00 am every day during summertime. I want to change it and get all my daily sum at 00:00 o'clock. I was wondering how to change the code to realize this then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr to calculate sum like :

```
precip$hour <-  strftime(precip$Datum,"%Y-%m-%d %H")
library(dplyr)
sum_hour <- precip %>% group_by(hour) %>% summarise(sum_hour = sum(mm,na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but neither it considers my last comment to @PierreLafortune 's answer. Looking forward to your solution!

Comment: do you mean if the hour is say 4:00, should it calculate for (3:00 to 4:00) ?, if so what will you do for 0:00 ?

Comment: yes, the sum of 4:00 should be 3:00-4:00 and the sum of 0:00 should then be the sum of 23:00-0:00... now this is tricky.

Comment: 23:00 from previous day ?